# Firebase - Check if Project name exists

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check the project name to see if it exists and, if it does, prompt the user with an error. I would like this to happen before the user submits the form, but if that's the only way then that's fine. I'm using Cloud Firestore.

I think I'm doing this completely wrong, I would love any help that I could get.

```js
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAddProjectComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data,
    private afsc: AngularFirestore,
  ) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-lifecycle-interface
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoadingCategory = true;
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2),this.asyncValidator.bind(this)],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.getCategories().subscribe((categories) => {
      this.isLoadingCategory = false;
      this.categories = categories;
      this.form.addControl(
        'categoriesFormArr',
        this.buildCategoryFormArr(categories)
      );
    });

   
  }

  asyncValidator(control) {
    const projectName = control.value;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.checkProjectName(projectName).then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
          resolve({
            'username taken': true
          });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      })
    })
  }
  checkProjectName(projectName) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('Projects').where('projectName', '==', projectName).get();
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(
      {
        arrVal: this.categoriesFormArraySelectedIds,
      },
      null,
      2
    );



    this.newProject.projectName = this.form.get('name').value;
   
    this.afsc.collection<Project>('Projects').ref.where('projectName', '==', this.newProject.projectName)
    .get().then((ref) => {
      const results = ref.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as Project);
      if (results.length > 0) {
        console.log(results, 'this sdid something?');
        return;
      } else {
        console.log('no user');
        return;
      }
    });
    this.newProject.projectDescription = this.form.get('description').value;
    this.newProject.interests = this.categoriesFormArraySelectedIds;
    this.firestoreService.createProject(this.newProject);

    this.dialogRef.close();
    // Add snackbar
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md">
          <div class="mt-4"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Project name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [class.is-invalid]="f['name'].invalid"
              formControlName="name"
              [(ngModel)]="newProject.projectName"
            />
            <div class="invalid-feedback mt-2" role="alert">
              Project name is required.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Project description</label>
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              [class.is-invalid]="f['description'].invalid"
              formControlName="description"
            >
            </textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback mt-2" role="alert">
              Project name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isLoadingCategory; else loadingTmpl">
            <label>Project Category</label>
            <div
              class="checkbox-group"
              [class.is-invalid]="f['categoriesFormArr'].invalid"
            >
              <div
                *ngFor="
                  let control of categoriesFormArr?.controls;
                  let i = index
                "
                class="checkbox"
              >
                <label
                  ><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="control" />
                  {{ categories[i]?.title }}
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              At least one category must be selected.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end"
    ><button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      [disabled]="form.invalid"
      [routerLink]="['', newProject.projectName]"
      routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are actually using Cloud Firestore and not the Realtime Database. I updated both the tags and the body of your question.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? For example: when you step through it in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I'm not 100% sure. I was looking into some information about this online and I saw this post. I'm not sure if i'm doing it properly though. Nothing really is happening.